# Optional Parameters with EF Core FromSql

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1

Is it possible to use EF Core FromSql to execute a stored procedure that has optional parameters?

I have been testing out a simple scenario to use as a template for updating old EF6 calls to EF Core calls.  The test example I am using as a proof of concept:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestNullableParameters] 
    @addressId int = null,
    @city nvarchar(100) = null,
    @createdByUserId int
AS
BEGIN
    select * from CRM..Address a
    where (@addressId is null or a.AddressId = @addressId)
    and (@city is null or a.City like @city)
    and a.CreatedByUserId = @createdByUserId
END
```

My test code that calls this proc:

```
[Test]
public void TestNullableParameters()
{
    var procName = "exec CRM..TestNullableParameters ";
    var context = _testContainer.Resolve<CRM2Context>();

    var addressId = new SqlParameter("@addressId", 182);
    var createdByUserId = new SqlParameter("@createdByUserId", 1620);
    var parameters = new[] {addressId, createdByUserId};
    var result = context.Address.FromSql(procName, parameters).ToList();
}
```

This code does not work, as it states the procedure requires "@createdByUserId", which was not supplied -- it attempts to map createdByUserId to @city, and then has no value to map to @createdByUserId.

If I try to define a parameter @city with value null, it states that the procedure requires a non-null value for @city.

If I try to explicitly add a parameter list with only @addressId and @createdByUserId, it states that it is missing non-nullable @city.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to skip the optional parameters, you should use the named parameter syntax

```
@parameterName = parameterValue
```

as explained in the [Specifying Parameter Names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/specify-parameters?view=sql-server-2017#specifying-parameter-names) section of the SQL Server documentation for executing stored procedures.

Once you do that, there is no need to deal with `DBNull` and `SqlParameter`s at all - you can use the `FromSql` overload accepting C# interpolated string and let EF Core create parameters for you.

Thus the sample code for calling the SP can be reduced to:

```
var result = context.Address.FromSql(
    $"exec CRM.TestNullableParameters @addressId = {201}, @createdByUserId = {1620}")
   .ToList();
```

Comment: How could I use this to also include an output int parameter?  In the same scenario, except the proc also has an ouput parameter,  I have tried passing in @totalRows OUTPUT in the sql string, and I have tried adding totalRows as an output parameter as a SqlParamter object.  Neither method has worked

Comment: I think set returning SP (`FromSql`) cannot be combined with output parameters. `Database.ExecuteSqlCommand` can be used with output parameters, but only with scalar result. EF Core limitation.