# Execute stored procedure with a default parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I need to use a stored procedure with three parameters. The second parameter is a default value. I am not allowed to modified the stored procedure. When I try to execute the stored procedure using Entity Framework, I am passing the first and the third parameters. And I am getting the error that the third parameter is not provided.

This is the signature of the stored procedure:

```
[dbo].[sp_CreateTest] 
      @Par1 NVARCHAR(25),
      @Par2 NVARCHAR(50) = 'Test',
      @Par3 NVARCHAR(50)
```

I am trying to execute it like this:

```
List<SqlParameter> parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Par1", "Parameter1 data"));
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Par3", "Parameter3 data"));

testEnt.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec dbo.sp_CreateTest @Par1, @Par3", parameters.ToArray());
```

Comment: You also pass the 2nd parameter from C#, but do not assign value to it. if you pass it without value, it will use the default value.

Comment: Thank you. Could you show me how not  to assign a value. If I do  parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Par2", null)); I am getting the error that the second parameter is not supplied

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: `var parameter = new SqlParameter(); parameter.ParameterName = "@Part2"; parameters.Add(parameter);`

Comment: I modified the code according to your suggestion and I am getting that the parameter @Part2 is not supplied

Comment: Duplicate of [Optional Parameters with EF Core FromSql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53213667/optional-parameters-with-ef-core-fromsql/53214931#53214931), but for EF6 `ExecuteSqlCommand`. The principle is the same though - use *named parameter syntax*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use "Default" as parameter in place of second parameter.
i.e.

"exec dbo.sp_CreateTest @Par1,DEFAULT,@Par3"

Comment: I tried your suggestion. I got the error that the @Par2 is not supplied

Comment: You have to use DEFAULT instead of Default

Answer (score 2):

One method is to use named parameter notation instead of positional notation so that default values are used for those not specified. This will also avoid tight coupling to parameter ordinals.

```
testEnt.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec dbo.sp_CreateTest @Par1=@Par1, @Par3=@Par3", parameters.ToArray());
```

Comment: This is, in my opinion based on experience, the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
 public class BlogContext : DbContext
 {

 public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

 public BlogContext(DbContextOptions<BlogContext> options) : base(options)
 {
 }

 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
     base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

     modelBuilder.Entity<Post>().Property(p => p.Text).HasDefaultValue("Default");
 }
```

}